# Using simple_list_item_2 and can't figure out how to use setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, menu, onclick, simpleadapter

Please excuse me, I'm new:new at this. I use a `simple_list_item_2` to display 11 items. These 11 items have been loaded by using `HashMap` and then `SimpleAdapter`. This works fine in displaying everything. The problem is that I cannot get `setOnItemClickListener`  going. The code:

```
public class TwoLineActivity extends ListActivity 
{

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(2);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scrolllist); 

        // enter valid data, these 2 are the same as the remaining 9
        HashMap<String, String> maplist;
        maplist = new HashMap<String, String>();
        maplist.put("line1", "a11 data");
        maplist.put("line2", "asd asd ad 1234569780");
        list.add(maplist);

        maplist = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        maplist.put("line1", "a12 data");
        maplist.put("line2", "asd asd ad 1234569781");
        list.add(maplist);

String[] from = { "line1", "line2" };

int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);  
setListAdapter(adapter);`
```

So up to here things are great, I get my list. Now I want to be able to select an item from the list, so I coded the next 2 lines

```
    list.setAdapter(adapter);  
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    { .....
```

I get the following errors

`The method setAdapter(SimpleAdapter) is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`

and

`The method setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`

Comment: *"without an error."* - What specific error do you get? Does your app crash? In this case please post the stacktrace. Thanks!

Comment: Your activity extend ListActivity or activity?

Answer (score 0):

If your activity extends ListActivity, you should override

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Pascal Piché, but the problem (As I didnt explain that right either) in in the  setAdapter and setOnItemClickListener.  I redid the question to hopefully be more specific